# C run concurrent processes, then kill them

Tags: c, signals, fork

I'm working on a program that spawns multiple processes via `fork()` and runs them concurrently. What I want is for the first process that ends to trigger a kill of all the other processes created. I'm getting stuck trying to figure out how to do this. I'm hoping for some suggestions. Here's what I'm thinking so far.

```
void done(int childid) {
  kill(something?,SIGKILL);
  printf("process %d signaling\n",childid);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Signal(SIGCHLD, done);
  pid_t pid;
  for (each command in an array) {
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
      setpgid(0,0);
      Execve(command stuff);
    }
    else if (pid > 0) {
      printf("starting process %d\n",pid);
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously this is rather sudo-coded, but the weird thing is that the ids I get back don't match the ones that started, and obviously the parent program ends before any of the children start returning. I'm just having a very hard time with the logic here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait you need to wait in the parent for the execution of the child.

Comment: What are `Signal` and `Execve`?  Do you mean the standard POSIX functions `signal` and `execve`?

Comment: Yes, forgive me @JohnBollinger, I should checked those.

Comment: @DamienBaldy, if I wait in the parent, won't that prevent them from being run concurrently?

Comment: No, the computer will run both processes in parallel.

Comment: @DamienBaldy, if I change the contents of the `else if` statement to read: `printf("starting %d\n",pid); while((pid = wait(&status)) < 1) {} printf("ending %d\n",pid);` it runs one after the other. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Easiest way to kill a group of processes is to call `setpgid` first, then create a bunch of processes which will inherit the pgid. Then you just have to use `kill(-pgid, signo)`. If this is homework and you have various constraints about what you can and cannot use, let us know.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, no constraints. Do I need to setpgid in each child? And do I need to generate the pgid somewhere, or just make one up?

Comment: The pgid is inherited, so you only need to set it once, before you begin to create children. When you set the pgid, it can either be the caller's pid (or 0, which does the same thing), or it has to be an existing pgid in the same session (typically this means login session). The latter is used by a shell to move background commands in and out of the foreground; you likely don't need to worry about that.